# Disease on Thuja Occidentalis

Tags: diseases, fungus, hedge, moss

In our garden there are two northern white-cedars (thuja occidentalis) that have gotten a strange light-greenish area on the base of their stem (see the image enclosed). The infected species are in direct neighbourhood to each other. So it might have spread from one bush to another. The area is visible for about two years now. Does anybody have an idea what this could be? To me it looks like a moss or any kind of fungal infection.

[image: Here is the]